# Jenkins - shared lib with copyArtifacts, NotSerializableException WorkflowJob

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

On Jenkins ver. 2.164.2, copyArtifacts plugin 1.42, 
I get the good old NotSerializableException WorkflowJob error when running a declarative pipeline calling a shared lib script, where a non serializable ( Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName) ) is passed along a copyArtifacts plugin call.

The error goes away when I comment either the copyArtifacts section, or the four def lines (`def job` to `def requiredBuildNumber` - the artifact is copied succesfully if I replace requiredBuildNumber.toString() with a number, e.g. `selector: specific('256')` .

I played with it for a couple of days and would love some advise, please!

My Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'windows' }

parameters {
    string(defaultValue: "JOB-NAME", description: '', name: 'getInfoFromJobName')
    string(defaultValue: "2", description: '', name: 'numberOfBuildsBack')
}

options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30'))
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    timestamps()
    ansiColor('xterm')
}


stages {
    stage('Get artifacts') {
        steps {
            cleanWs()
            checkout scm

            getLabInfoFromPrevLab jobName: "${params.getInfoFromJobName}",
                    numberOfBuildsBack: "${params.numberOfBuildsBack}",
                    getSuccessfulBuild: false
        }
    }
```

Where the shared library holds the script \vars\getLabInfoFromPrevLab.groovy:

```
def call(Map params = [:]) {

def jobName = params.jobName
def numberOfBuildsBack = params.get('numberOfBuildsBack', 0)
def getSuccessfulBuild = params.get('getSuccessfulBuild', true)


def job = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
def lastReferencedBuild = job.getLastBuild()
def lastReferencedBuildNumber = lastReferencedBuild?.number.toInteger()
def requiredBuildNumber = lastReferencedBuildNumber - numberOfBuildsBack.toInteger()

copyArtifacts(projectName: jobName,
        selector: specific(requiredBuildNumber.toString())
)
```

}

The full error:

```
an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@27356c83
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@79592d5f
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@33d11a06
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@52a3b953
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@1caca328
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@1caca328
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor139.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1019)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2438)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:500)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:476)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:463)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:387)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:259)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:247)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Maybe try setting `requiredBuildNumber` to `null` after using it for the `copyArtifacts` method. Also, would `lastReferencedBuildNumber` possibly being assigned a value of `null` not cause runtime errors for this code?

Comment: To expand on @MattSchuchard's comment, I think it would be easier to calculate `requiredBuildNumber` from `currentBuild` instead of the last build. That way you won't have to worry about null values. Also you can write a debug prompt `println requiredBuildNumber` to see if the value refers to any real build or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to discard all vars used hudson object before copyArtifacts: 
job = lastReferencedBuild = lastReferencedBuildNumber = null

Comment: It was actually job and lastReferencedBuild that were in the copyArtifacts' way. Cheers Vladi

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to your question: according to the official shared libs [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps),

> Library classes cannot directly call steps

And according to the [pipeline steps reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/), copy artifacts it **is** a step.

To solve the issue, the documentation offers you several options. I personally prefer the usage of static methods in the shared lib and so can the script been passed to the lib and there, call the step:

Your function call:

```
getLabInfoFromPrevLab
    script: this,
    jobName: "${params.getInfoFromJobName}",
    numberOfBuildsBack: "${params.numberOfBuildsBack}",
    getSuccessfulBuild: false
```

And the function implementation:

```
def call(Map params = [:]) {
    def jobName = params.jobName
    def numberOfBuildsBack = params.get('numberOfBuildsBack', 0)
    def getSuccessfulBuild = params.get('getSuccessfulBuild', true)

    params.script.copyArtifacts(projectName: jobName,
        selector: specific(requiredBuildNumber.toString())
)
```

Disclaimer: this current implementation **not** tested